# Ruby: Where is STDERR.puts defined?

Tags: ruby, stdout, stderr, puts

I understand that the normal `puts` function that you regularly use in Ruby to write to stdout out is defined in the module `Kernel`, so to override it you would just do something like this:

```
module Kernel
  def puts(*args)
    # do custom logic
  end
end
```

However, overriding this puts function doesn't seem to affect `STDERR.puts`. What module is `STDERR.puts` defined in?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to override `STDERR.puts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `IO`. You can check it like this:

```
STDERR.method(:puts).owner
#=> IO
```

Answer (score 0):

`STDERR` is an instance of `IO`; which separately overrides `puts`. So there are two different things you could do here:

1. Reassign `STDERR` to a new object of your own design (probably a bad
   idea)
2. Override `IO#puts` (definitely a bad idea)
3. `def STDERR.puts ....` (not such a bad idea; but I can't imagine doing it myself)

Answer (score 0):

```
[32] pry(main)> STDERR.class
=> IO
[33] pry(main)> STDERR.method(:puts)
=> #<Method: IO#puts>
[34] pry(main)> class IO
[34] pry(main)*   def puts(arg)
[34] pry(main)*     raise "OVERRIDE"
[34] pry(main)*   end
[34] pry(main)* end
=> :puts
[35] pry(main)> STDERR.puts "test"
(pry):35:in `puts': OVERRIDE (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: There are literally hundreds of questions like this one on [so], and the answer to all of them is more or less the same: the easiest way to find out where a method comes from, is simply to ask the method: `STDERR.method(:puts).owner #=> IO`. I am always surprised by the fact that people would rather spend minutes writing a question, then waiting potentially hours for answers, which may possibly even be wrong, instead of just checking themselves.

Comment: Overwriting `IO#puts` in order to alter `STDOUT.puts` might not be the best idea, because it will affect any `puts` call that's based on `IO`, e.g. all `File` related `puts`, `STDOUT.puts` and even the global [`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts).

Comment: Yeah, I can't speak to what the intent of this is.  The answer is more about how to look up where the method is defined, rather whether or not is it a good idea to overwrite it.  The overwrite is there just to prove it was in fact defined on IO.